# jQuery - traverse xml and create list of it

Tags: jquery, xml, traversal

I am trying to traverse XML and get the `label` attribute of my `set` node and create a list but I am not able to traverse correctly. Can someone please explain how to traverse and create a list?

**Here** is [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sohampshetty/7JLtH/41/)

The XML is

```
<chart caption='View by Law Category' subcaption='Law Category' xAxisName='null' yAxisName='Count' bgColor='AAFFAA,FFFFFF' exportEnabled='1' exportAtClient='1' exportHandler='fcExporter1' showLabels='0' showValues='1' showLegend='1' legendBorderAlpha='0' legendBgAlpha='0' legendShadow='0' formatNumberScale='0'>
    <set label='1495cat' value='2' link='j-loadImpactChart-Law Category:1495cat' />
    <set label='Category Test' value='35' link='j-loadImpactChart-Law Category:Category Test' />
    <set label='Labour' value='149' link='j-loadImpactChart-Law Category:Labour' />
    <set label='New Law 1' value='58' link='j-loadImpactChart-Law Category:New Law 1' />
    <set label='testing' value='4' link='j-loadImpactChart-Law Category:testing' />
</chart>
```

I have tried `alert($('chart>set').attr('label'));`

```
$($xml).each(function(){
    alert($(this).find("chart>set").attr('label'));
});
```

Comment: How are you getting the XML, ie what is the value of `$xml`? The `$` preceding it would imply it's a jQuery object already. Also, does your XML have multiple `chart` nodes? A more complete XML sample would really help a lot.

Comment: Actually Im using fusion chart and this is xml im using to create pie chart. i have only one chart and xml is also same what i have given

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
var xml = "<chart caption='View by Law Category' subcaption='Law Category' xAxisName='null' yAxisName='Count' bgColor='AAFFAA,FFFFFF' exportEnabled='1' exportAtClient='1' exportHandler='fcExporter1' showLabels='0' showValues='1' showLegend='1' legendBorderAlpha='0' legendBgAlpha='0' legendShadow='0' formatNumberScale='0'><set label='1495cat' value='2' link='j-loadImpactChart-Law Category:1495cat' /><set label='Category Test' value='35' link='j-loadImpactChart-Law Category:Category Test' /><set label='Labour' value='149' link='j-loadImpactChart-Law Category:Labour' /><set label='New Law 1' value='58' link='j-loadImpactChart-Law Category:New Law 1' /><set label='testing' value='4' link='j-loadImpactChart-Law Category:testing' /></chart>";
var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml)
$(xmlDoc).find("chart > set").each(function(){
    alert($(this).attr('label'));
});
```

Comment: Tried but its throwing error before that unexpected identifier. please check fiddle

Comment: Updated your fiddle, please check (http://jsfiddle.net/7JLtH/42/). Unexpected token error coz, string was not in the same line. Updating my answer too.

Comment: Thank you. but in my project its throwing `$.parseXML is not a function` error on console please help to resolve

Comment: Hope you are using jQuery lib and you have imported it.